# Enviar dois parâmetros de uma vez via ajax

Tags: javascript, html

Estou enviando uma informação com ajax, mas gostaria de enviar duas de uma vez. Seria possível adaptar o código abaixo para isso ?

```
  <select name="sex" class="" required>
<option value="1"> Woman </option>
<option value="2">Man </option>
</select>


     <select name="country" class="country select" required>
<option value="1">Exemple 1</option>
<option value="2">Exemple 2</option>
<option value="3">Exemplo 3</option>
</select>
```

O javascript é esse

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".country").change(function()

{
var country_id=$(this).val();
var post_id = 'id='+ country_id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "../conexao/ajax.php",
data: post_id, 
cache: false,
success: function(cities)
{
$(".city").html(cities);
} 
});

});
});
```

No arquivo php que receber, tenho isso

```
  <?php
include('conexcao.php');
if($_POST['id']){
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];

if($id==0){
 echo "<option>Selecione seu nome</option>";
}else{
 $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `teste` WHERE sex = $sex");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
 echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['nome'].'</option>';
 }
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passe um parametro adicional no data do seu ajax:

```
data: {id: $('.country').val() , sex: $('.sex').val()},
```

Irá ser enviado as duas informaçoes do select escolhido no html.

Comment: Olá, primeiro obrigado por tentar ajudar. Fiz a substituição como vc sugeriu, na parte do meu ajax. SUBSTITUI >> data: post_id,  << pelo código que você disse, mas não funcionou... :(

Comment: Adicione o  class="sex" no input de SEX , delete estas duas linhas " var country_id=$(this).val(); " e "var post_id = 'id='+ country_id;" . Agora veja se não funciona. e coloque o código que te enviei no lugar do "DATA" no ajax.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou Bartollo, vc é fera, abraços !